# Spark: How do I query an array in a column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Please I'm new to Spark (Stackoverflow as well). For the following RDD and DataFrame (same data) I want to get the most viewed tags of playlists with over N videos. My issue is that tags are in an array, in addition I don't know where to start as it seems advanced.

#### RDD

```
(id,playlist,tags,videos,views)
(1,playlist_1,[t1, t2, t3],9,200)
(2,playlist_2,[t4, t5, t7],64,793)
(3,playlist_3,[t4, t6, t3],51,114)
(4,playlist_4,[t1, t6, t2],8,115)
(5,playlist_5,[t1, t6, t2],51,256)
(2,playlist_6,[t4, t5, t2],66,553)
(3|playlist_7,[t4, t6, t2],77,462)
```

#### DataFrame

```
+---+------------+--------------+--------+-------+
| id| playlist   | tags         | videos | views |
+---+------------+--------------+--------+-------+
| 1 | playlist_1 | [t1, t2, t3] | 9      |  200  |
| 2 | playlist_2 | [t4, t5, t7] | 64     |  793  |
| 3 | playlist_3 | [t4, t6, t3] | 51     |  114  |
| 4 | playlist_4 | [t1, t6, t2] | 8      |  115  |
| 5 | playlist_5 | [t1, t6, t2] | 51     |  256  |
| 2 | playlist_6 | [t4, t5, t2] | 66     |  553  |
| 3 | playlist_7 | [t4, t6, t2] | 77     |  462  |
+---+-------------+-------------+--------+-------+
```

#### Expected Result

Tags for playlists with more than (N = 65) videos

```
+-----+-------+
| tag | views |
+-----+-------+
| t2  | 1015  |
| t4  | 1015  |
| t5  | 553   |
| t6  | 462   |
+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For the given example, can you edit the post to include the _expected result_? Your description (`most viewed tags of playlists with over N videos`) is somewhat vague, an example would help resolve any ambiguity.

Comment: Added table based on OP's description of desired results, "most viewed tags [for] (playlists with over N videos)"

Comment: Exactly! Please can you help on that @TzachZohar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using DataFrames:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val N = 65

val result = df.where($"videos" > N)           // filter playlists with enough views
  .select(explode($"tags") as "tag", $"views") // explode tags into separate records
  .groupBy("tag")                              // group by tag
  .sum("views")                                // sum views per tag

result.show(false)
// +---+----------+
// |tag|sum(views)|
// +---+----------+
// |t5 |553       |
// |t4 |1015      |
// |t2 |1015      |
// |t6 |462       |
// +---+----------+
```

And with RDDs:

```
// given 
val rdd: RDD[(Int, String, Array[String], Int, Int)] = ???

val N = 65

val result: RDD[(String, Int)] = rdd
  .filter(_._4 > N)
  .flatMap { case (_, _, tags, _, views) => tags.map(tag => (tag, views)) }
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tzach, is there a way to do it with RDD since I want to know difference ...

Comment: added solution with RDDs, but I recommend reading through the documentation for the RDD API which should give you everything you need to figure out this type of transformation

Comment: Ok I will give it a shot. BTW for dataframes I'm getting duplicated tags (e.g. t2 with X sum of views and t2 with Y sum of views, instead I want t2 | X+Y)

Comment: Oh I solved, I just had to remove spaces after the split ;)